# How to enable Google Custom Search Autocomplete

Tags: google-custom-search

We are using Google custom search engine(Paid).We are not using google search control.How to implement the Autocomplete(query Suggestions) feature programatically. Is there any specific API for autocomplete

Answer (score 2):

You can easily enable autocomplete in your GSS/CSE account:
https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2631081?hl=en

And then wait some time for automatic autocompletitions to be generated by Google.

If "*not using google search control*" means "*we are using plain HTML form*", then try this:

```html
<form id="searchForm" action="http://google.com/cse">
  <input type="hidden" name="cx" value="013315504628135767172:d6shbtxu-uo" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8" />
  <input type="text" name="q" size="31" id="searchText" />
  <input type="submit" name="sa" value="Search" />
</form>
<img src="//www.google.com/cse/images/google_custom_search_smwide.gif">

<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('search', '1');
var autoCompletionOptions = {
  'maxCompletions' : 3,
  'styleOptions' : {
    'xOffset' : 10
}};
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
  google.search.CustomSearchControl.attachAutoCompletionWithOptions(
    "013315504628135767172:d6shbtxu-uo", document.getElementById('searchText'), 'searchForm',
    autoCompletionOptions);
});
</script>
```

Of course, autocomplete should be enabled for that GSS/CSE (like described on the link above) no matter what you are using - CSE element or HTML form.

Comment: Major upvote for this. With GSS being expired on April 1, 2018 a lot of legacy sites suddenly found their auto-complete broken and the original developers are long gone (I just had a client beg me to fix this which I did, thanks to you!)